# Unwanted JavaScript file in Firefox, NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: javascript, firefox

I don't know why but I get JavaScript error only in Firefox, also I see some unwanted JavaScript file in my page that I never referenced to them before.

[image: firefox error]

[image: javascript error]

What's this? Actually I want to know what's this unwanted JavaScript file in my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it's because of one FireFox extension that automatically included some external javaScript files to all of pages and it's prevent Firebug to work well.

Removing extension solved all problems.